# Python SQlite как добавить строку в виде списка(list) в таблицу?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Здравствуйте! Не смог разобраться и нигде не вижу ответа. Ситуация такая. Я формирую строку, которую мне нужно потом добавить в базу данных, в виде списка(list). Но как теперь сформулировать запрос, чтобы добавить этот список в базу?

Всё вроде понятно, когда у меня в таблице постоянное количество столбцов, например:

```
list = [1, 10, 15, 37]
c.execute('INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)' % tuple(list) )
```

Но что если я не знаю заранее количество столбцов? То есть по ходу работы программы колличество столбцов может увеличиваться. Как тогда сделать запрос?

Я вышел из положения таким образом:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i] = str(list[i])

list_text = ', '.join(list)
c.execute('INSERT INTO chrom VALUES (%s)' % list_text)
```

Ну то есть я просто склепал запрос в виде текста.

```
>>>print(list_text)
"1, 10, 15, 37"
```

Сдаётся мне, что это костыль совершенно неприличный, и ход через одно место. Подскажите кто-нибудь, пожалуйста, как сделать по уму?

Comment: Кстати в большинстве языков такой метод не подошел бы, потому как драйвер бы видел один параметр а values требовал бы много. Как вариант, делать символьную строку `'%s'+',%s'*(длина_списка-1)` и подставлять в values ее. (я так понял в питоне строки можно вот так размножать умножением)

Comment: @kff: это не нормальная практика. Форматирование конкретных значений в sql запросе ведёт к SQL injection. https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Не используйте строковое форматирование значений при создании запросов***. Это может привести к [SQL injection](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Используйте параметризированные запросы вместо этого. Например, не делайте вот это:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)' % tuple(list_)) #XXX DON'T DO IT
```

Делайте вот это:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO table VALUES (?,?,?,?)', list_)
```

Конкретный язык для параметров зависит от драйвера базы данных ([`sqlite3` понимает `?`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)).

Если количество колонок заранее неизвестно (что указывает на возможную проблему с моделью данных), то можно создать шаблон: `','.join('?' * len(list_))`:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s)' % ','.join('?' * len(list_)), list_)
```

Не используйте встроенные имена (такие как `list`) для своих переменных -- это затрудняет чтение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, так и сделаю)